# Error "Not enough storage" using FileLoggingSession

Tags: uwp, etw

Experimenting with Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics FileLoggingSession I am getting the Exception "Not enough storage is available to process this command".  Up to a point the files seem to get deleted automatically. Regardless of what I do in the LogFileGenerated event I run into "Not enough Storage". Why is this happening?

```
Private _trace As New LoggingChannel("TraceChannel", New LoggingChannelOptions())
Private _fileLoggingSession As New FileLoggingSession("TraceSession")
Private _bufferedTracesFolder As StorageFolder

Sub New()
    _fileLoggingSession.AddLoggingChannel(_trace)
    AddHandler _fileLoggingSession.LogFileGenerated, AddressOf _fileLoggingSession_LogFileGenerated
End Sub

Sub _fileLoggingSession_LogFileGenerated(sender As IFileLoggingSession, args As LogFileGeneratedEventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine(args.File.Path)
    'args.File.DeleteAsync().AsTask.Wait()
    'HandleTraceFile(args.File).Wait()
End Sub

Async Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    _bufferedTracesFolder = Await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("LatestTraces", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
    Await GenerateTraces()
End Sub

Async Function GenerateTraces() As Task
    Dim random As New Random
    Await Task.Run(
        Sub()
            For i = 0 To 1000000
                Dim txt As New String("x", random.Next(50, 1000))
                _trace.LogMessage($"{i} {txt}")
            Next
        End Sub)
End Function
```

[image: File Explorer screen shot]

[Complete code sample here.](http://1drv.ms/1RIHzJr)

This looks like a bug in FileLoggingSession to me.

I my understanding FileLoggingSession works as follows:
FileLoggingSession internally uses a bounded buffer. When its bound is reached it flushes the messages to a disk file. If no LogFileGenerated event handler is attached it creates log files until the disk is full. If a LogFileGenerated event handler is attached (to allow us move away the file) the file gets deleted automatically after executing the event handler.

Thus FileLoggingSession should never consume more memory then the bounded buffer size and not more disk storage space than 1 log file. Both limits are undocumented but seem to be about 256KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this as a bug [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/10740987-error-not-enough-storage-using-fileloggingsessio)

Does someone know a better place to post such bugs?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but I just ran into this and thought others might find the information useful.

As of today (2017-08-14), the bug still is there. There is a workaround: Regularly kick off an asynchronous operation and await it. While your thread is idle, the logger apparently uses it to dump events to the log, to rotate log files, and whatnot. But who would want to sprinkle his code with `await Task.Delay( 500 );`?

One other thing. The logs as created by ETW are named `(app)-Log-Session-#.etl` or so, where `#` increases from 1 as log files are rolled over. When a registered log-rollover handler is notified, the log is renamed to use the number 0, so the handler always sees `(app)-Log-Session-0.etl`.

Regrettably, when using `FileLoggingSession.CloseAndSaveToFileAsync()`, the rename doesn't always happen, yet the file name passed to the handler receives the name as if the file had been renamed … lovely.

The "logging" UWP sample shows both bugs. For the first one, just remove the Task.Delay() in `FileLoggingSessionScenario.cs`; the second one is more elusive, but you can try causing a few extra forced-closes for the log (suspend app etc.)